# VB6 to VB.NET equivalents

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I'm trying to convert some VB6 code to VB.Net

```
Private Sub MSComm1_OnComm()
    Dim RxNumeric As String

    Dim i As Integer

    Rx = MSComm1.Input
    RxNumeric = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(Rx)
        SReply(i - 1) = Asc(Mid(Rx, i, 1))
        RxNumeric = RxNumeric + " " + Hex(SReply(i - 1))
    Next i
    txtWindow.Text = RxNumeric
    Replied = True
End Sub
```

My question is:
what is `MSComm1_OnComm` in VB.Net?

If this somehow should be inside `serialport_DataRecieved`, what should I include?

Comment: `MSComm1_OnComm` isn't anything in VB .NET.  This code defines a function called `MSComm1_OnComm`.  So in VB .NET you would achieve the same thing by similarly defining a function by that same name.  Have you tried anything?  What didn't work?

Comment: i've tried copying and pasting it... i pasted it under `SerialPort_DataRecieved`... i don't really know where to place this... thanks

Comment: Well, copying and pasting code between different development environments probably isn't going to be very effective.  If you're making some attempt to implement some functionality in VB .NET and are stuck on something, we can certainly help with that.  But if you're asking "where in .NET do I copy/paste this VB 6 code" then we can't really answer that because the question itself doesn't make any sense.

Comment: i know, as you can see i'm not familiar with vb6, and `MSComm1_OnComm` is obsolete, so i've studied about serial ports... the question is what's the equivalent of `MSComm1_OnComm` in .net so that i can place the codes under it...

Comment: See [Moving Your Legacy Hardware Code to Visual Basic 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364066(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: thanks @Idle_Mind!been searching for days for this equivalent. i've not searched enough.

Comment: @David does `Len(Rx)` = `Rx.Length` and `Hex(SReply(i - 1))` = `Conversion.Hex(SReply(i - 1)` the same?

Comment: it seemed that my `SerialPort_DataReceived` is not working...i'm new with serialports... i only started studying it several nights ago.
 i dont know what could have caused it because 
can't get Boolean to True ~

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
WithEvents MSComm1 As SerialPort

Private Sub MSComm1_DataReceived(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles MSComm1.DataReceived
    Dim RxNumeric As String
    Dim i As Short

    Dim Rx As String = MSComm1.ReadExisting
    RxNumeric = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(Rx)
        SReply(i - 1) = Asc(Mid(Rx, i, 1))
        RxNumeric = RxNumeric & " " & Hex(SReply(i - 1))
    Next i
    txtWindow.Text = RxNumeric
    Replied = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Same** as @EJD's answer, but **OPTIMIZED**:

- I favour `Int32` over Int16,
- don't use LEGACY methods (in favour of `managed` ones) and
- take advantage of using `Using` and
- the `StringBuilder` object

---

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
WithEvents MSComm1 As SerialPort

Private Sub MSComm1_DataReceived(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles MSComm1.DataReceived

    Using RxNumeric As New StringBuider
        Dim Rx As String = MSComm1.ReadExisting

        For i As Int32 = 0 To Rx.Length - 1
            SReply(i) = Convert.ToInt32(Rx.Chars(i))
            RxNumeric.Append(" " & Convert.ToString(SReply(i), 16))
        Next i

        txtWindow.Text = RxNumeric.ToString()
    End Using

    Replied = True
End Sub
```

I could also get rid of the SReply array, but I left it - just for readability.